Hyperthreading: SIMD and scalar execution at the same time. Is it possible?
I have a question regarding cpu execution. A CPU can hyperthread, by letting different processes use different components of the cpu at the same clock cycle. But I wonder if this can be used to speed up programs. Lets say program A just does some multiply add operations. For this it uses a very optimized SIMD instruction. Let's say we want to get the last piece of performance out of the cpu, can we run simd and scalar executions in parralel on one cpu core and on the same program?
For example you execute a function where you do 20% the scalar way and 80% of the SIMD way.

Yes, although most SIMD code also includes scalar instructions like incrementing pointers and loop branches.  On many CPUs (e.g. Intel and some ARM), SIMD and scalar instructions compete for the same execution ports (since multiple execution units share the same port), although some like AMD have separate schedulers and execution units for SIMD/FP.  https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/amd/microarchitectures/zen_2 vs. https://www.realworldtech.com/sandy-bridge/6/
See also Modern Microprocessors
A 90-Minute Guide! re: superscalar basics.
It's also not rare for SIMD code to be limited by the front-end (instruction fetch/decode) if it doesn't bottleneck on cache/memory bandwidth, assuming it has a good mix of load, store, and computation.  Maybe less common on the latest Intel and AMD CPUs with wider front-ends (5 or 6 wide, up from 4 since Core 2) but still only 3 vector ALU execution ports (Intel.  Or 2 with 512-bit uops in flight.)  Intel since Haswell has a 4th ALU execution port that only handles some scalar integer and branch uops.
Hyperthreading (and other non-Intel SMT implementations) just alternates front-end cycles between logical cores, unless one is stalled (e.g. branch mispredict, or its half of the ROB (reorder buffer) is full due to a cache miss).  So SMT can increase front-end utilization but in most designs can't get more peak throughput than a single thread.  (But most real-world code isn't written with an instruction mix that can achieve that.)

Hyperthreading means that you have one processor, with the capabilities of a single processor, but with the ability to execute instructions from two instruction streams. Compared to two processors, which would have twice the resources but at doubled cost, your performance gain is less, but the additional cost is less.
Imagine you have perfectly optimised code that completely uses all the resources of your processor and then you use hyperthreading. All resources are already used. There are no extra resources. You won’t gain any extra performance.
Now look at rather bad code. The processor could do say three operations per cycle, but your code has a ton of dependent operations and only managed one instruction every four cycles. Now you use hyperthreading. The second thread has plenty of leftover resources, but its code is just as bad and it also does one instruction every four cycles. Performance is still bad, but it’s is doubled!
There is a theoretical limit what your processor can do; how much of that limit you get depends on your code. Hyperthreading lets you get closer to that limit. If your code gets 100% of theoretical performance you get no change. If your code got 60% it might go to 80%. 10% will go to 20%. So mostly hyperthreading fights inefficiencies in your code.
Now SIMD for example has nothing to do with this. Efficient SIMD code will gain little, inefficient SIMD code will gain a lot, as with any other instructions.
There is a special case when you mix instructions. Consider a processor that can do three floating point instructions or six integer instructions due to its execution units, but only three instructions because of limitations to the instruction stream. With hyperthreading the limit is 3fp, 3int, but 6 total. So if one thread does 3fp, the other can do 3int at the same time, but it couldn’t do another fp instruction.

It depends on the CPU whether integer ALU instructions compete for some of the same execution ports as SIMD/FP ALUs.  On Intel for example they do, on AMD they don't so it's just a front-end bottleneck.  https://www.realworldtech.com/sandy-bridge/6/ vs. https://chipsandcheese.com/2022/11/05/amds-zen-4-part-1-frontend-and-execution-engine/ .  So for example on Alder Lake, 6-wide front end, back-end 3 FP/SIMD per cycle, but only room for one more integer ALU uop in cycles when 3 FP/SIMD uops dispatch to execution ports.
